# difference between client API and server API

Tags: java, .net, asp.net-web-api, client-side

As mentioned in the topic, can someone explain the relationship between the client API and the server API?

For example, we have a web with its server written in java and use Axis2. I get access to the source code and find there is a folder called 'client_API' and all the codes are written in JAVA. What exactly does client API do? It works at server side or client side?(From its name I think it should work on the client side, but the client side is just a user's browser, but how could a browser read the JAVA code?).

Comment: Obviously we're guessing, but it's likely it's the public-facing API, e.g., what clients access.

Comment: The client usually invokes the server over a transport (say HTTP) using a message level protocol (such as JSON) and sends requests. The server understands the request and responds. There can be several clients written in different languages and what is common between them is the network and message protocol. That is how the client and server are decoupled. It's hard to narrow down the answer further based on the information you provided. More here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service

Comment: This sounds like a good question for your coworkers who know the product!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you say that something is in `Client-Side`, this means it is executing on your application context. `Server-Side` means it will be executed from another machine, a remote machine, a server.

In fact, when we say something is `server-side`, in many cases, we are considering it will be executed in the server or a remote machine but we also can says that is a `web service` or a `SOA` - [`Service-oriented architecture`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) based application, `REST` based applications.

For sample: the Web Browser (client) execute some code (client-side code), and make requests to server  side that will execute some code there (server-side) and response something to the client. Look the image:

[image]
<sub>(source: [webstepbook.com](http://www.webstepbook.com/supplements-2ed/slides/images/figure_2_client_side_scripting.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Web services are generally describes as client and server but perhaps you'd prefer the classical [Stubs and Skeletons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_skeleton#Protocols_using_stub.2Fskeleton_approach) explanation. The client_api is a [stub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_stub). From the wikipedia article,

> The stub acts as a gateway for client side objects and all outgoing requests to server side objects that are routed through it.

[image: Stubs and Skeletons]

Comment: I found that in the build process of a web, the 'stub' will be generated automatically on server, the name could be 'ExampleAPIStub.java'. I assume that this will be used later. But as the diagram shown above, the Stub works on a client, or a user's browser. But the generated stub is on the server. Any explaining? @Elliott Frisch

Comment: Not exactly, the client-api is a stub. Your confusion seems to stem from the fact that your web server is also a (web-service) client.

Answer (score 0):

Here is link which explains Client Side API and Serve Side API

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ablxhelp/v8r4m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.abx.ref.doc%2Fsii-bloxobjectmodel-93524.html

Most of the time/or all of the time Client API will be in JavaScript. The primary reason for having client side API is to easily and seamlessly access server side API and logic.

Also Java applets which are just JavaByteCode and are platform independent (hmm... ) is supported by every browser and can run on Client machine.

Answer (score 0):

it's probably just a web services client. Take a look at detailed description on Axis site:

[Creating clients.](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html#createclients)

[Creating Services.](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-buildingservices.html#buildservices)

Basically you can have a web service client that "consumes" the service provided by a web service "Service". It looks odd at the beginning but keep going with your studies that soon these concepts will be in your mind.

You can have a Web Service client that is hosted on your Application Server, written with Axis 2 Java APIs for example, or you can have a WS client that is written in JavaScript and executed directly from a browser, it really depends what and how the application you're looking at is designed.